# List all (private) repositories of a GitHub organization

Tags: rest, github, curl, github-api

I am the owner of a GitHub organization. All repos in that org are set to private.
In the web UI dashboard, I can see that there are 112 repos in my organization. However, when I request all repositories via API (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories) I only get around 30 of these back.

```sh
curl -i -u username:oauth-token https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos
```

Adding a query string like `?type=all` to the URL does not make any difference.

Thank you for your help and ideas.

K

Answer (score 1):

By default GitHub API returns 30 results per page here. Just as said in the doc link, try setting `per_page` (max 100) to get more:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos?per_page=100
```

And use `page` parameter to get next pages:

```
https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos?per_page=100&page=2
```

Comment: I've tried that, it didn't work. I found the solution here: https://github.community/t/issue-about-the-parameters-per-page-and-page-in-the-api/134622/3

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to use the [paging query parameters](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-organization-repositories) AND to [quote the request URI](https://github.community/t/issue-about-the-parameters-per-page-and-page-in-the-api/134622/3).

```sh
curl -i -u username:oauth-token "https://api.github.com/orgs/org/repos?per_page=100&page=1"
```